# Flex: Different width for different tabs in tab navigator

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, actionscript, flex3

Is there some way to have a tab navigator in flex where each tab width can be controlled explicitly ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes that can be done. The following example grabs the tab at index 0:

```
yourTabNavigator.getTabAt(0).width = 200;
```